# Fixed element with links in it gets overlapped by div with text in it

Tags: html, css, fixed

So I have started building my first 'real' website, and pretty soon I ran into a problem. The `fixed` navigation bar at the top of the site gets overlapped by a `<div>`or a `<p>` tag, (both of them with a lower `z-index` than the element that gets overlapped. The fixed element doesn't get visually overlapped, but you can't click the links when it is in front of other elements. I have no idea how to fix it, and did not find a solution on Google.

Here's sample code:

```
<body>
<div id="Nav"> <a href="http://brochmann.se/"><p id="navicon">Brochmann.se</p></a>
 <a id="navtext1" href="#">link</a>
 <a id="navtext1" href="#">another link</a>

    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <p>This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.
            This is a test text i just made for a problem i have.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    font-family: Noto Sans;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -2;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#headtxt {
    /*titeltext*/
    position: relative;
    color: #F0F4C3;
    text-align: center;
    top: -300px;
    font-family:Lobster;
    font-size: 700%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#Pic {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 300px;
    /* avstånd från headern till övrigt innehåll *magisk punkt* */
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #E6EE9C
}

#Nav {
    /* fäst navbar i toppen av fönstret*/
    position: fixed;
    /*background-image: url("head.JPG");*/
    /*samma bild som i headern*/
    background-color: #F0F4C3;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top:0px;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: -5px 10px 20px #888888;
    height:40px;
}

#headimg {
    /*bakgrundsbild till headern*/
    opacity: 1;
}

#navicon {
    color: #AFB42B;
    font-family: Lobster;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 150%;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    top: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 1;
}

#navicon:hover {
    color:white;
}

#text {
    /* brödtext*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: -5;
}

/*#navcontainer{
        background-color: #E6EE9C;
        width:13%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -2;
        margin-top: -34px;
        display: inline;
        position:relative;
        top: -12px;
      }*/

#navtext {
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;
    margin-left: 18.5%;
    /*borde vara 20, ingen aning om vad som är felet*/
    text-align: center!important;
    text-align: -moz-center;
    color: #F0F4C3;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: larger;
}

#navtext1 {
    margin-left: 18.5%;
    /*borde vara 20, ingen aning om vad som är felet*/
    text-align: center!important;
    text-align: -moz-center;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: larger;
    color: #AFB42B;
    position: relative;
    left: -11.75%;
    top: 25%;
    z-index: 4;
}

/* FF9800 - orange #CDDC39 - Lime */
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw0kmk3w/)

I'm not very good at HTML, so it could be pretty messy but I simplified it a lot

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean the links get overlapped? For me the menu bar on the Jsfiddle is on top of everything, the `<p>` text is going below of it. isn't this supposed to be like this?

Comment: I am confused as well... maybe it's only on a certain type of browser (looks OK here in Chrome) - what browser are you using?

Comment: It doesn't seem to get overlapped, but you can't click the links when they are in front of the text. You may have to scroll a bit down to actually get the fixed bar in front of the text. @Chun

Comment: @ochi I am using chrome as well, but as i said in the previous comment, the bar doesn't get visually overlapped, you can't click the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar is staying behind of all the content because you're telling it to stay behind the content with the `z-index:-1;` in your `#Nav`. By removing this line from your `#Nav` will fix this problem.

```
#Nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #F0F4C3;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1; /* <======= THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE REMOVED <======= */
    box-shadow: -5px 10px 20px #888888;
    height: 40px;
}
```

**Jsfiddle [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/tw0kmk3w/5/)**

Although I think you are misunderstanding the concept of `z-index` because I notice that you are using `z-index` in many classes and IDs. Use it only when it's really necessary.

**Note:** `IDs should be created for unique divs as well, when used more than once you should exchange these for classes instead.`

### About z-index

The z-index property determines the stack level of an HTML element. The “stack level” refers to the element’s position on the Z axis (as opposed to the X axis or Y axis). A higher z-index value means the element will be closer to the top of the stacking order. This stacking order runs perpendicular to the display, or viewport.

http://www.websiterox.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/zindex.gif
http://www.lakotuts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/figure020.gif

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a margin-top for the text :

```
#text {

/* brödtext*/

position: relative;
margin-top:50px;
z-index: -5;

}
```